# What is common.chunk.js?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have an Angular 5 app, running with angular-cli 1.6.6, when bundle my app, I have (within all the others) a **common.chunk.js**.

Do you know what it is? It does not match with any of my modules, it's also not the **vendor** or the **main** or the **polyfill** because they have their dedicated chunk.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

The common chunk is a place for all the things that more than one of your feature modules use.

Let's say you have a custom grid component in a custom `grid` module. You then import this grid module into your `user` and `admin` feature modules. Because the `grid` module is used in more than one feature module, Webpack stitches it into a `common.chunk` that the other feature modules depend on.

If you run the build with chunk naming turned off (`--named-chunks false` - used by default in `--prod` builds), the `common.chunk` becomes `0.chunk` - the zeroth chunk that has to be loaded before any other lazy chunks.

One downside of this is that if you have a lot of small lazy modules in your app (which I think is the case judging from the screenshot), the `common.chunk` will start to get bloated particularly quickly. Say two of your lazy modules use some awesome (yet chubby) charts library. All of the tree-shaken code from the charts library will end up in the `common.chunk`. Even though the other lazy modules do not use any of this pile of chart code, they still do depend on the `common.chunk` and will load and execute all of the charts code they don't need.

To see what's what, you can use the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to inspect the insides of your built chunks. You can either `npm i --D` it or use `npx` to not bloat your dev dependencies.

```
ng build --prod --stats-json && npx webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json
```

Hope this helps a little :-)

Comment: Great answer, but is there no way to tell angular something like - "Don't put this in the commons chunk" or "Don't put anything in the commons chunk unless it has been used in over X feature modules" or "Don't put anything over size xyz in the commons chunk" ?

Comment: I don't think so... You can do that by ejecting your Webpack config and specifying the behaviour precisely yourself. On the other hand, `ng 6` should be able to optimise for the common bundle problem by creating 'intermediary' common bundles - eg. things `A` and `B` are used only in module `X` and module `Y` -> a common chunk, containing only things `A` and `B` will be generated and depended on only by bundles for `X` and `Y`. I think this should come sometime around the Ivy compiler release.

Comment: thanks, spending a few hours now inevitably upgrading to ng 6.  Oh happy days

Comment: @AugieGardner did it work? I upgraded and don't see anything other than common.js. I'm passing `"enableIvy": true` into `angularCompilerOptions` as it says to do here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/STATUS.md .

Comment: @Michael Pearson Ivy is still not ready for being used, outside of tinkering around with. If you have your lazy loading set up correctly, new bundles should pop up, aggregating shared functionality among lazy modules that use it. The common chunk remains but holds only functionality that is used by many lazy modules (which should make it much smaller - it went down from 1.2MB to 25kB in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is the webpack common chunk https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/

It can be disabled with `--no-common-chunk`